# Get the process triggering signal in modelsim

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I'm using modelsim to debug my vhdl written ideas. Now I've got an "Iteration limited reached". OK, I know why this happens(but still cannot find my bug^^).

So the question is: How do I see in modelsim which signal(from the sensitivity list) triggers my process?

Comment: The Modelsim SE User Guide has a section entitled **Detecting Infinite Zero-Delay Loops**, wherein you produce a debug optimized image of your model (e.g. *vopt top +acc*) and then run vsim with *+autofindloop*. You'll get "the vsim-3601 error again, but this time with information about zero- delay loops."  (modelsim_se_user.pdf, ModelSim SE 10.2c).

Comment: Process triggering signals, are signal whose `'event` attribute is high. So you can report the signal by writing a big if-elsif...elsif statement.

Comment: Step by step execution or breakpoints at selected positions are a simple and efficient way to observe your code during execution.